# Can we take out "cpu_count()" value?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to build an executable from a Python multi-threading script using  "pyinstaller". And I want to use the number of threads of the destination computer (it's not constant).

I fear that `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` value comes from the building computer even if the number of threads is different from the destination PC.

Can we take out the value?

Comment: Hi, `cpu_count()` will be evaluated at runtime. So no matter where you run the script it will be for that computer. In this case, the computer running the EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fear that `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` value comes from the building computer even if the number of threads is different from the destination PC.

It doesn't, it is a runtime call.

AFAIK, pyinstaller does not build anything to native code. Instead, it bundles a Python interpreter with your own code (or its bytecode representation). Thus your program is still interpreted and should retain the same behavior.